# Importing some data from an Excel file to another

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel file (Cartel1) which contains information about a set of workers (id, name, surname, position and payroll).

Information about payroll are missing but available in a second file (Cartel 2), where I have many more individuals and the same set of variables. I would like to import information about payroll from Cartel 2 into Cartel 1. Of course, I want to import only information about the subset of individuals in Cartel 1 (not the entire Cartel 2).

I am stuck as I cannot figure out how I can do that. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

[Cartel 1](https://unimeit-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/dmaimone_unime_it/ERUadBdGSXNDlqg0Q313K4UBOTkGo0FjiwKujHHRB16jZw?e=wvX50e)

[Cartel 2](https://unimeit-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/dmaimone_unime_it/EfIRscfAYx1PntxkmcFFiE4B-U7NpmYIzMOA5YlxGoBNvA?e=0stjSS)

Answer (score 0):

First, you need access to the second workbook's data in the first workbook. You may use external references (described below) or copy the data from workbook "Cartel 2" into a separate worksheet called "Source" in workbook "Cartel 1".

Now, to import the payroll into cell E2, use the following formula:

`=INDEX(Source!$E$2:$E$21, MATCH(1, (B2=Source!$B$2:$B$21) * (C2=Source!$C$2:$C$21) * (D2=Source!$D$2:$D$21), 0))`

Note that this is a CSE formula! Thus you **need** to enter it via the 'Control+Shift+Enter' key combination (just the 'Enter' key won't work).

You can, now, drag E2's formula and fill cells E3:E11.

### External references

If copying the data is an inconvenience you may want to use external references. They are used to refer to cells located in other workbooks. `Path[Filename]Sheet-name!Cell` refers to a cell with coordinates `Cell` on worksheet `Sheet-name` of workbook `Filename` located in folder `Path`. E.g. instead of `Source!$E$2:$E$21` you will have to write `/path/to/the/second/workbook[Cartel 2]Foglio1!$E$2:$E$21`.

## How does this formula work?

- In Excel (as almost everywhere), true conditions are denoted with number 1, while false conditions are denoted with number 0. Multiplication (denoted with an asterisk) can be used to check several conditions. E.g. `=(A1=A1)*(1>0)` will result in `1` because both conditions are true and `1*1=1`, whereas `(A1=A1)*(1<0)` will result in `0` as the second condition is false and `1*0=0`.
- `$` is used to fix a value so that it doesn't change when the formula is dragged to neighbouring cells. E.g. formula `=B2` would be transformed into `=B3` if it was dragged to the lower neighbour. `=B$2` would remain the same.
- External references are described above.
- Now, `(name=B2:B21)` is an array formula. It operates on an array of size 20 (`B2:B21`). It will result in an array of the same size: `{name=B2, name=B3, ..., name=B21}`.
- Thus `name=B2:B21`, `surname=C2:C21` and `position=D2:D21` will result in three arrays of the same size (20). Multiplication will result in an array of the same size containing the products of corresponding elements.
- Now notice that this array will contain `1` in positions which match `(name, surname, position)` which is exactly what we need! To find that position function `MATCH` may be used. It's general syntax is:
- `MATCH(niddle, haystack, mode)` to find value `niddle` in range `haystack` with matching mode `mode` and return the position. Mode `0` means exact match, so our formula will look like:
- `MATCH(1, (name=B2:B21) * (surname=C2:C21) * (position=D2:D21), 0)`
- At last function `INDEX` may be used to retrieve the payroll at that position. The general syntax is:
- `INDEX(range, position)`
- Summing up:
- `INDEX(Source!$E$2:$E$21, MATCH(1, (B2=Source!$B$2:$B$21) * (C2=Source!$C$2:$C$21) * (D2=Source!$D$2:$D$21), 0))`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually, when I enter the fomula above an use Control+Shift+Enter I get an error message saying tha tthe formula is not correct. If I look at it, I cannot find any mistake. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: @Dario Maybe your version of Excel doesn't support some of the used features. I'll add some details about how the formula works, so you can try to use the features separately and find the missing one. Btw, you may also check that a comma is used for list separator and not a semicolon.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I copied exactly that formula - also using Italian names for index and match - but it keeps saying there is an error. Specifically it points to $E$2:$E$21. I use the latest version of excel. I will try again. Btw if i use match and index separately they work. And i enter the formula via control+shift+enter

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet2!$B$2:$B$21=Sheet1!B2)*(Sheet2!$C$2:$C$21=Sheet1!C2)*(Sheet2!$D$2:$D$21=Sheet1!D2),Sheet2!$E$2:$E$21)
```

[image]